# SQL Query about blob length

Tags: sql, mysql

Is there a way to query a MySQL database that gives me all blobs that are bigger than 1kb?

Comment: Upvoters, care to explain why such a one-manual-glance question is voted?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Try using the [`LENGTH()`](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/string-functions.html#function_length) function on the blob field.